# What are some popular web services to find Esperantists by location?

Tags: resources, websites

I tried searching [Pasporta Servo](https://pasportaservo.org/), [Esperantujo](https://esperantujo.directory/), and Facebook with some cities I have lived in or am planning to (all European with 500,000+ population), but usually found less than 5 scattered Esperantists with not many common interests. I'm sure there would be more – if nothing else, judging by the sole fact that in my previous location I met one randomly who is on none of these sites. (But unfortunately that's quite a while ago and we didn't establish contact then.) My next closest Esperanto friend lives 2500 km away.

The problem is that I have no means of detecting which pages are *a priori* known. Esperantujo looks a bit too new for that, for example, with less than 1500 records altogether. For example, it lists no more than 2 members in all of Slovakia despite the yearly congresses in Nitra. Pasporta Servo, of course, is famous, but the problem there is that people who aren't interested in the service itself (e.g. don't have a spare room and don't travel themselves) don't have much reason to join.

Is there a "usual" **generic purpose** website where Esperanto speakers would go to sign in to find each other based on location?

The closest I can think of now is to just join various online groups and *ask* who's where. But that depends on who will ever see the question, in groups or chat rooms with many people it can easily slide below. A static search, with a map perhaps, would be preferred.

Comment: Note also that the rules of Pasporta Servo specifically prohibit using it as a general tool for finding Esperantists for any other purpose than requesting an overnight stay.

Comment: @TomasoAlexander I was afraid that would be the case. That's a significant difference from Couchsurfing where you can mark that you're just open to hanging out with visitors to the location. Ad the duplicate – thanks for pointing it out! I didn't see it in search. Yet I'm somewhat hesitant to clicked "That solved my problem" because I'd be looking for a centralized solution (in which case that would hint at the answer being a "no"). Ted's answer below is directly towards this particular question, I'll first see if it opens a bit more discussion.

Comment: Exactly this kind of website is something I've been missing. I agree with much of what you're saying. I also don't think this is a duplicate, since the other targets clubs. The majority of the esperantists I know aren't members of any club. This doesn't imply they aren't interested in meeting other esperantists. Finding them requires other methods though.  The former system of lernu was good, but the site targets beginners, and it's down now anyways. Esperantujo.directory fulfills many of the things I want, and the updates has made it better and better.

Comment: Yeah, Esperantujo looks like it has a lot of potential, but unfortunately it isn't getting a lot of activity; it shows me as the only E-ist in Colorado, and other places have similar representation... and when I post about it on social media I get likes and +1s but the map stats stay the same...

Comment: Regarding whether this question is a dup: I've copied the answer from the other question and posted it below changing 'club' to person. The method is the same.

Comment: In such case I'm accepting the dup. It's a pity there's nothing more centralized at this point, let's hope that lernu! and the other methods will be up and running soon!

Answer (score 8):

An app is being developed, kind of like Grindr or Tinder, called Amikumu. It's not quite ready yet, but once it is, I think it will serve your purposes.

Comment: Probably best to limit answers to websites and services that actually exist. Amikumu cannot find speakers who don't exist and, like the many sites given in the original thread, it can't find people who don't sign up for it. Don't wait for Amikumu - sign up for chatterplot, mondmapo, and so on.

Comment: It has been brought to my attention that Chatterplot is defunct. The mondmapo (https://esperantujo.directory/) is still alive and well and could use more people adding their names. Myself, I'm findable by a simple Google search for "esperanto" plus my city name. The fact that I'm not being overrun by people contacting me suggests that the simple answer is the correct one. People aren't looking - perhaps the reason why Chatterplot failed and Amikumu will have many challenges.

Comment: Chatterplot failed for many reasons. We are well aware of their week points as we closely worked with them (before they shut shop). They failed because they couldn't finance their operation. Amikumu has no issues in this department.
People are most definitely looking for an easy way to find others. Your suggestion of Google + City name usually turns up very limited results. Most Esperanto speakers aren't associated with "associations" and "clubs" so they won't show up in Google searches. In large cities this may help but in smaller towns it's near useless.

Answer (score 5):

[Lernu.net](http://lernu.net) has a search feature that allows you to search users by location. Right now the messaging isn't working so you won't be able to message them at this time. However, you could find their username and search for them in Google, which will hopefully reveal some of their social media accounts with the same username.

Answer (score 4):

The answer to your question is no. There is not one obvious single best way to find Esperanto speakers by city. There has been a lot of talk lately about Amikumu, but nobody knows how it will actually work and how effective it will be because it has not been released yet.

In the meanwhile, there are a couple of possibilities:

1. google Esperanto + cityname
2. search on Facebook for Esperanto + cityname
3. ask the Esperanto organization of the country how to contact the local group and ask them.
4. ask on Telegram in one of the language groups or in the main group, be patient
5. ask on Facebook in the biggest Esperanto group (more than 20k people)
6. Check meetup.com
7. Contact the Esperanto club of a neighboring city.
8. Search Duolingo for references to your city name.
9. Check out the search tips at "Trovu Samurbanon" on FB (https://www.facebook.com/Trovu-samurbanojn-E-istojn-%C4%89ie-586767024717907/)
10. Chatterplot (no longer operational.)
11. Mondmapo (https://esperantujo.directory/)

Comment: Chatterplot is defunct. It was shutdown a while back.

Comment: That's too bad. I hadn't heard. I'm just looking for more info - the site seems to be down but all the social media is up and running but with no updates. At any rate, I'll remove it from my answer.

Comment: I've worked with their marketing department before. They were struggling financially for a while and even tried to sell the website. Unfortunately, they couldn't get the positive cash flow they needed and were forced to close shop.